# Using a dropdown list in a formula to get information from another worksheet

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, dropdown

I have a workbook that has three worksheets: `Data`, `TeamMembers` & `MasterFileLinks`

The following formula works just fine for retrieving the data I need - 
`=AVERAGEIFS(MasterFileLinks!D3:D10000,MasterFileLinks!AH3:AH10000,"Joe Schmoe")`, the formula is in `Data!C3`.

My `TeamMembers` sheet is the source for the dropdown list (also named `TeamMembers`).

My dropdown list appears in Cell `A6`; for testing purposes I use names like Mickey Mouse and Donald Duck.

What I would like is that when I use the dropdown list to go from Joe Schmoe to Donald Duck that it would pick the data from MasterFileLinks for Donald Ducks

Is there a way to insert something into the formula like the dropdown box name or something like that instead of the persons name so that the data retrieved from the `MasterFileLinks` page is based off the dropdown list?

Thanks

Comment: I imagine you mean that you are using the object of a dropdown, rather than data validation? If you are using data validation, you can simply reference the cell like @Jeeped has mentioned in their answer. If not, you may need to assign the "Linked Cell" property to cell `A6` so that you can use it in the formula or in the object's change event perhaps assign a cell's value (or the first entry in a named range `SelectedMember`) and update that to the dropdown's `.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=AVERAGEIFS(MasterFileLinks!D3:D10000, MasterFileLinks!AH3:AH10000, A6) 
'I'm pretty sure you should be able to use full column references
'try this beside the original and compare
=AVERAGEIFS(MasterFileLinks!D:D, MasterFileLinks!AH:AH, A6)
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you so much.  Out of all the things I tried just having the Cell A6 was not one of them.  Greatly appreciated.